# Send Data from aspx to C# windows app

Tags: c#

I want to send data from my Windows form to client wep page(.aspx).Pls help me.

Comment: Please clarify, which direction you mean? WinApp -> Asp.net or Asp.net -> WinApp

Comment: Can you post some more details on your requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse to do this. it will be easy to do also.check the link below

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could use Web Services within your ASP .NET application and consume them them from your WinForms app.

Give a look to these articles:

- [Web Services with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx)
- [Using ASP.NET Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Calling XML Web Services from Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scf355x6%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.NET Remoting](http://www.developer.com/net/cplus/article.php/1479761) for doing this. Your desktop app can act as a remoting server, whereas your web app will be the remoting client.

The marshalled object exposed by your server (Windows app) will be accessed by the web application, which will call a method for getting the data. Your windows app will provide the data as a serializable object to your web application, which it will deserialize and process.

Answer (score 0):

ther are several ways,

1) If you want to send data from window app to Web App then Use Query String.

2) If you want to send data from Web App to Windows app then you can User Either Remoting or Webservice.

3) You can user Biztalk Server for Integration.(this would be quite expensive).

4) You can build your own messaging mechanism, write all you information into a file and ask you application to read the file.